# Beautifulsoup locating elements in bs4.element.tag by div.div.div..?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, beautifulsoup

So I have an item whose type is bs4.element.tag

```
> atag = item.a.div.div.div.div
  <div class="_1cRBf1"><div class="_3VombQ"></div></div>
```

It's a long story but I'm trying to use the .div.a.span or something like this to get the elements and I wanted to get second element from atag variable ()

Is there a way I can do like

```
> atag = item.a.div.div.div.div[2]
  <div class="_3VombQ"></div>

# OR

> atag = item.a.div.div.div.div[class="_3VombQ"]
  <div class="_3VombQ"></div>
```

to get the second div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method:

```
item.a.div.div.div.div.find_next(class_="_3VombQ")
```

Comment: yes i already know this but I'm asking if there is a way to find it by .div.div.div[2] or something like that to get the second <div>

Comment: @DHK I edited my answer. You can use the `find_next()` method. `.find_next(class_="_3VombQ")` or (I'm not really understanding your HTML, but:) `.find_next('div')`

Comment: You can also try to use .`contents` For example:: ...`div.contents[1]`

Comment: thanks, curious but if I had "data-seq" or like an "id" instead of "class" would it still be the same by just changing it with "class_"?

Comment: @DHK Correct. And for id you use `.find(id=MY-ID)`. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

From the comment you gave on MendelG's answer, I assume you just want to find the nth child of a div or some other type of element... Right?

If so, that's easy... just do something like

```
element = soup.select("item>a>div>div>div>div:nth-child(2)")
```

That will return a list. To print it:

```
print(element[0])
```

There's a whole bunch of css-selectors you can use at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp